# Glide elements horizontally on touch devices

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building something like a Netflix queue, where I create a line of items that extend past the viewport

```css
.row {
  overflow:scroll;
}

.slider {
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="slider">
      <div class="square">Foo</div>
      <div class="square">Foo</div>
      <div class="square">Foo</div>
      <div class="square">Foo</div>
      ...
```

This works well enough, but it would be nice to be able to flick through the items on my tablet and get the row of items to glide and slow down with friction. I've been able to achieve that effect in the past vertically by employing iframes, but I don't know how I can get something similar horizontally.

A CSS solution would be ideal, but would take a Javascript solution as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2013/10/16/the-flick-scroller/

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch,   does what you are looking for but at the moment supported only on mobile safari

Comment: @MichaelB and it turns out Android already implements the desired behaviour. This is great, feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile safari has this css property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`
which gives scrollable containers the momentum effect you are talking about.
I currently don't know of any other browser implementing this feature.

[Momentum Scrolling on iOS Overflow Elements](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)